# Telegram bot: How do I hide inline keyboard ? PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I made a telegram bot with an inline keyboard.(via `InlineKeyboardMarkup`)
I like to *hide* (or make it *one-time*) keyboard after user response.
How can I do that in PHP?

Here is a view of my bot:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is method [`editMessageReplyMarkup`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup). You can transfer empty `inline_keyboard` param. But it's may not working on some devices (i have problem with iphone, for problem devieces you can edit markup to "thanks" button, and after remomeve it)

Answer (score 7):

Try updating the message with editMessageText method and empty markup.

Answer (score 2):

actually by getting the message ID and using `deleteMessage` you can make the keyboard disappear.

here is the description >> [Telegram Bot ApI](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage)
i hope this help you