# How to hide or delete inline button after click?

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram-bot

I have used dialogflow for telegram bot. Now I need to remove or delete after a user clicks on the button.
Here my custom payload code

```
{
  "telegram": {
    "text": " STORE\n\n BANK ACCOUNTS ",
    "parse_mode": "HTML",
    "reply_markup": {
      "inline_keyboard": [
        [
          {
            "text": " LOG, PASS, ACC, ROUT",
            "callback_data": "REFUND POLICY"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "text": " AUSTRALIAN BANKS",
            "callback_data": "REFUND POLICY"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "text": "Back",
            "callback_data": "Store"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please check sceer shot 
[image]

when a user clicks on back button need to remove the inline keyboard

I've tried "hide_keyboard: true"

But it didn't work.

Comment: may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898132/telegram-bot-how-do-i-hide-inline-keyboard-php

Answer (score 2):

There is no `hide_keyboard` option in Telegram bot API. The [`ReplyKeyboardRemove`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove) method is present, but it is used for hiding **reply** keyboards, not **inline** keyboards like yours.

---

There is no explicit `hide` method for inline keyboards in Telegram bot API. You can either change previously sent keyboard or simply delete message which contains keyboard.

To change inline keyboard of sent message, use [`editMessageReplyMarkup`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) method. Just provide a new version of inline keyboard in `reply_markup` parameter, which will replace the current one.

To delete the entire message use [`deleteMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use something like this:

```
def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")
```

Also don't forget to add CallbackQueryHandler in main function:

```
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
```